# How to add bootstrap only for one component(React)

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

My application is in React and using css for styling. I wanted to add modal in one component. For that I am using bootstrap. But after adding bootstrap to my project entire UI is looking messy. How can I limit bootstrap to only one react component.

**Task:** Creating feedback form using bootstrap modal
**Issue:** bcz of bootstrap UI is changed 
**Requirement:** Want to limit the bootstrap only for feedback component!

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I would assume it is because bootstrap expects to be the main way a site is styled.

Comment: how can I change it and limit to only one component? Is it possible?

Comment: I wouldn’t think so due to the way the framework works. The CSS styles are added and applied at the page level. For scoping you may need to use another tool, like styled-components or CSS modules. (I may also not be aware of a scoped version of bootstrap)

Comment: If you were using Next.js you would be able to do that very easily, but in your case I think you need to choose a different option or override bootstrap's styles on the components you don't want to use it, but it will be painful and not recommended.